# If $f=f_{1}-f_{2}$ with $f_{1},f_{2}\geq0$ a.e. then $f_{1}=f^{+}$ and $f_{2}=f^{-}$? (measure theory)

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions

In measure theory the decomposition $f=f^{+}-f^{-}$ for a measurable function $f$ is commonly used, where $f^{+}=\max(0,f)\geq0$ and $f^{-}=\max(0,-f)\geq0$. Now suppose that $f=f_{1}-f_{2}$ with $f_{1}\geq0$ and $f_{2}\geq0$ almost everywhere. Can we conclude that $f_{1}=f^{+}$ and $f_{2}=f^{-}$? I don't think this need to be true, but I cannot come up with a counter example. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated

Comment: Surely not. You can always choose $f_1 = f^+ + g$, $f_2 = f^- + g$ with an arbitrary nonnegative (measurable) function $g$. Or more simply: $0 = 1 - 1$.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for your reply! I see your point.

Comment: It's true if you also assume that $f_1$ and $f_2$ have disjoint support (for every $x$ either $f_1(x)\ne0$ or $f_2(x)\ne0$.)